# Stuck on spring data jpa left join giving multiple record with same data

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot

I am getting multiple same entries while running query from spring jpa

Here is my query

```
    @Query(value = "Select * FROM t1" + 
                "   LEFT JOIN t2 im ON t1.id=im.id", nativeQuery = true)
public List<GetList> getList()
```

this query  gives me right data when run on mysql but on spring jpa it is giving me duplicate records
t2 has multiple records for t1 id
Here is result for my sql

```
t2Id  id 
1   605
2   605
3   605
4   605
5   589
6   589
7   589
9   606
    2
    5
    6
    15
    16
    29
```

Here is entity

```
@Entity
public class GetList {
@Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Integer Id;

@Column(name = "t2Id ", unique=true,nullable=false)
    private Integer t2Id  ;
}
```

Here is result from spring jpa

```
t2Id  id 
4   605
4   605
4   605
4   605
```

t2 table data with some more fields

```
t2Id  id 
1   605
2   605
3   605
4   605
5   589
6   589
7   589
9   606
    2
    5
    6
    15
    16
    29
```

t1 data

```
status  id 
 Active 605
 Active 589
 Active 606
 Active 2
 Active 5
 Active 6
 Active 15
 Active 16
 Active 29
```

I have tried many things but of no use. Any Solution would be helpful

Comment: Do you really want to this `t1.id=im.id` ? I don't understand the relation, may be you want to do  `t1.t2id=im.id`

Comment: id is foreign key for t2 and id is primary key t1, t2Id is primary key for t2

Comment: i have updated the post

Comment: Is that really an `@Entity` or just a DTO? You also need a proper equals/hashcode and `t2Id` needs to be a list/collection else you will get a `Getlist` for each row. Also how can it be that `id` is the primary key? As 605 has 4 occurrences, while the key should be unique? So either this isn't an entity but a DTO (as mentioned before) or the key should be both fields OR the `t2Id` should be a collection.

Comment: it is a dto also 605 is primary key for t1 there it has only 1 ocurrence

Comment: i want the data to come as it is coming through query

Comment: If it is a DTO then don't annotate it with `@Entity` or, as stated, make the `t2Id` a collection. If you want a `GetList` per row, ditch the annotations and use a proper JPQL with the DTO to fill it. Or just write JDBC to map it using a `JdbcTemplate`.

Comment: did you try {distinct} keyword for duplication , if this is your problem

Answer (score 0):

According to your comments it is a DTO and not a managed entity for JPA. Ditch the annotations and add a getter/setter for each property.

```java
public class GetList {

    private int id;
    private int t2Id;

    public void setId(int id) { this.id=id;}
    public int getId() { return this.id;}
    public void setT2Id(int t2Id) { this.t2Id=t2Id;}
    public int getT2Id() { return this.t2Id;}

    public void hashCode() {
        return Objects.hashCode(this.id, this.t2Id);
    }

    public void equals(Object other) {
        if (other instanceof GetList) {
            GetList that = (GetList) other;
            return this.id == that.id && this.t2Id == that.t2Id;
        } 
        return false;
    }
}
```

Spring Data JPA will now use this as a projection and not a managed entity.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue before and I fixed it using a Set:

```
public Set<GetList> getList()
```